# Build error Sony Togari android Aosp

Tags: android, build, android-source

I am using sony xperia z ultra aka togari VM 5.5 GB ram ubuntu 16.xx

Any idea to resolve this?

> packages/apps/FMRadio/AndroidManifest.xml:44: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'roundIcon' in package 'android'  build/core/package_internal.mk:243: recipe for target 'out/target/common/obj/APPS/FMRadio_intermediates/src/R.stamp' failed make: *** [out/target/common/obj/APPS/FMRadio_intermediates/src/R.stamp] Error 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether you have `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` attribute in the `<manifest>` tag of AndroidManifest.xml file.

Also check whether your `targetSdkVersion` is set to 25 in your app level build.gradle file.